# BaylorEdPsych Package for RStudio; Can't install package

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to use the Littles Test out of the BayorEdPsych-Package to test for MCAR assumption.
For whatever reason though, my R can't find this package. Is it even still available?

My R Version: R 4.0.3 GUI 1.73
My R Studio Version: Version 1.4.1103

This is the error I get when trying to run install.packages().
The link to that side doesn't really help me.

Is there an alternative test for the MCAR/ MAR assumption? It's not a completely accurate test either way, but it would help me tremendously.

```
install.packages("BayorEdPsych")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘BayorEdPsych’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Zero Pancakes pointed out, `BayorEdPsych` isn't on CRAN anymore. I would recommend you use `mcar_test` from `naniar` package that provides an updated function for the same test. The documentation reads:
"Code is adapted from LittleMCAR() in the now-orphaned BaylorEdPsych package". Also, the `naniar` package is a wonderful package for missing data and it helps to be familiar with it.

You can find the function documentation here: http://naniar.njtierney.com/reference/mcar_test.html

Update:
The `mcar_test` function, for now, is only present in the development version of the package `naniar`. Install it like this:

```
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("njtierney/naniar")
```

Or you can just source the function from the github repository:

```
devtools::source_url("https://github.com/njtierney/naniar/blob/master/R/mcar-test.R?raw=TRUE")
```

Comment: I was able to install and load the naniar package, but for whatever reason, I get the error, that mcar_test is not part of it/ can't be found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot the function is in the development version only. I update response.

Answer (score 2):

[It was removed from the CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BaylorEdPsych)

[There is an older version](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/BaylorEdPsych/)

[How to install .tar.gz package in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/169599.html)

I've never installed a .tar.gz package before, but it seems possible

[Also there is a MCAR function in the Colmp v1.0 package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CoImp/versions/1.0/topics/MCAR)

Answer (score 0):

BayorEdPsych isn't on CRAN anymore, but you can install the older verions I think.